# Mysql returns duplicate in html table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to populate html table with data from mysql.But i am stuck on this part where each time i add some data it keeps repeating. On the picture below you can see that Test 1 repeat each time for every P20,P21,P24,P22,P23 and i needed to be one TEST1 for all of them. When i add Test 2 with value 19000 its making new P20 and all data come from Test 1 to Test 2. Can someone help me how to fix this.Any hint or suggestion wil be appreciated. Thank you all very much (Sorry for my bad english)

[image: I would like to make it like this]

This is code that runs this

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT Pers.naam, Rol.funkcija,pdata.broj
FROM ids
left JOIN Pers ON ids.persid = Pers.id
left JOIN Rol ON ids.rolid = Rol.id
left JOIN pdata ON ids.pdataid = pdata.id


';

$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

$testing = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>P Small <small>(NONE)</small></th>

        <?php
        foreach ($testing as $test):
            ?>
            <th>
                <?php
                echo $test['naam'] . '<br />';

                ?>
            </th>
            <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>TESTING LINES</th>
    </tr>

    <?php  foreach ($testing as $test): ?>
    <tr>  
     <td><?php echo $test['funkcija']; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>



        <?php 
        foreach ($testing as $test):
            ?>

            <td><?php echo $test['broj']; ?></td>
            <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to have it like this
[image]

Comment: Run the query in phpMyAdmin or similiar and look at the results. Then work out how to process the data properly

Comment: It would also be useful for you to show us how you want the output to actually look

Comment: Also as you have no parameters to this query, the prepare is unnecessary and is just adding another round trip to the database server for no benefit. You could simply use a `->query()`

Comment: Hi @RiggsFoll, Thank you for fast reaction on this. When i run query in phpmyadmin i get the result that P20 have Test 1 with data 20000 , P21 have Test 1 with data 21000 etc... So i need to have one Test 1 For all P. with different data in it.do you have any suggestions on it?

Comment: Hi @RiggsFoll , i added a link on how its supposed to be..

Comment: So now you just have to recode the script to match the query results and you required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some refactoring required to get to the output you want.

You seem to be enumerating quite a lot of data from your SQL result, so there is some grouping required to make things easier.

To get the appropriate number to each "naam" and "funkcija" you can use `array_filter` which however could theoretically return several numbers in each case.

You'll also have to nest a couple `foreach` instead of running them after one another.

If I understand your data structure correctly, this should at least give you a good starting point for the output you want:

```
<?php

// ...
$testing = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$naams = array_unique(array_column($testing, "naam"));
$funkcijas = array_unique(array_column($testing, "funkcija"));

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>P Small <small>(NONE)</small></th>
        <?php foreach ($naams as $naam): ?>
            <th>
                <?php echo $naam; ?>
            </th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>TESTING LINES</th>
    </tr>

    <?php  foreach ($funkcijas as $funkcija): ?>
    <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $funkcija; ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($naams as $naam): ?>
            <?php
                $data = array_filter(
                    $testing,
                    function ($v) use ($naam, $funkcija) 
                    {
                        return $v["naam"] === $naam && $v["funkcija"] === $funkcija;
                    }
                );
                foreach ($data as $value): ?>
            <td><?php echo $value["broj"]; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```